# Assign values to variables outside of the lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I want to assign a value to a variable thats located outside of the lambda expression. For eg.

```
model.Categories =
   productService.GetAllCategories().Select(
      c => new CategoryViewModel 
      {
          CategoryId = c.CategoryId, 
          CategoryName = c.CategoryName, 
          IsSelected = c.CategoryId == cat 
          //how can i also assign the CategoryName to model.SelectedCategory?
      }).ToList();
```

`model` also contains a property of `SelectedCategory`, which I want to assign the `CategoryName` to it if `c.CategoryId == cat`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just do something like this afterwards:

```
model.SelectedCategory = model.Categories.Single(c => c.IsSelected).CategoryName;
```

Ideally though, I'd just have SelectedCategory be a property dynamically returning that, rather than a set value that could fall out of sync:

```
public string SelectedCategory
{
    get 
    {
        Category selected = Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.IsSelected);
        return (selected != null ? selected.CategoryName : String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not crazy about this style of programming as it quickly becomes unreadable but it can be useful in some situations:

```
model.Categories =
    productService.GetAllCategories().Select(
        c =>
            {
                if (c.CategoryId == cat)
                    model.SelectedCategory = c.CategoryName;
                return new CategoryViewModel
                {
                    CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                    CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                    IsSelected = c.CategoryId == cat
                }
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: The lambda could be refactored into a new method, like `.Select(c => GetViewModelForCategory(c))` which has the benefit of being able to unit test the conversion logic. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done in that query. I'm afraid it is going to have to be in a seperate query; something like this (after `model.Categories` is assigned)

```
var selectedCategory = model.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.IsSelected);
if(selectedCategory != null)
{ 
    model.SelectedCategory = selectCategory.CategoryName;
}
```

Comment: This will assign a Category object to the SelectedCategory; the desired result is to assign the CategoryName to the SelectedCategory.

Comment: @Metro ah! missed that part. fixed!